# When Calabash iOS sends me ***** in its results, what does that mean?

Tags: ios, ruby, calabash

client: ruby-2.1.5/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.16.3
server: "version":"0.16.2"

I added some debugging around map(). A normal query returns this:

{:query=>"button marked:'Other options'", :method=>:query, :args=>[{:isEnabled=>1}], :r=>{"status_bar_orientation"=>"down", "results"=>["*****"], "outcome"=>"SUCCESS"}}

I don't know how to interpret *****.

In map.rb's assert_map_results "*****" is a failure case, so it's obviously bad.

In the simulator log, I see things like

Oct 12 17:37:57 TimBs-MacBook-Pro.local[36121]: -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f7f6fe4f730
Oct 12 17:37:57 TimBs-MacBook-Pro.local[36121]: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f7f6fe4f730'

which I presume is it trying to decide whether it can apply isEnabled to the string "*****" instead of an object that behaves like a map.

Why on earth did they choose something so uninformative and pigging hard to web-search for?

---

Update: I originally had

```
element = "button marked:'game hot icon norm'"
element_exists(element) && query(element, :isEnabled).first.eql?(1)
```

but found a reference to

```
query("button isEnabled:1")
```

which I misread and adapted as query("button", isEnabled:1). This didn't help, but wasn't the cause of the "*****" results. Unfortunately, going back to a known good state, and gradually working back to the problem state, never caused the issue to re-appear, despite git saying there was no real difference. I can only suspect a dirty build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means you tried to call a unknown selector on an Objective-C object.
In this case, something is calling `objectForKey:` on an instance of `NSString`.

What is the query or gesture you are trying to run?

Is it:

```
query("button marked:'Other options'", [{:isEnabled => 1}])
```

If so, then the problem is that `NSButton` does not respond to `isEnabled:` (notice the trailing `:`). That is the accessor. The setter is: `setEnabled:`.

If you are trying to filter by enabled-ness:

```
query("button marked:'Other options'", :isEnabled)
```

If you are trying to set the enabled state:

```
query("button marked:'Other options'", [{:setEnabled => 1}])
```

> Why on earth did they choose something so uninformative and pigging hard to web-search for?

It is difficult to change because Calabash is stuck in 0.x and uses semantic versioning so the API cannot be changed until a 1.x version.  I believe (but I can't recall) Calabash 2.0 gives a better notice.